# Should the replica version match between replicas of the same shard in SolrCloud

Tags: solr

I have a solr cloud (5.2.1) with 5 shards a 2 nodes.

In this cluster i have 163.463.543 items. I indexed 200.000 more items and now the versions / sizeInBytes between two nodes of a cluster are not consistent anymore.

```
shard1   | sizeInBytes | segmentCount |  version |
--------------------------------------------------
replica1 | 71325055021 |           14 | 11877844 |
replica2 | 71330161457 |            8 | 11877874 |

shard2   | sizeInBytes | segmentCount |  version |
--------------------------------------------------
replica2 | 71658372259 |            9 | 11965329 |
replica1 | 71660446852 |           17 | 11965305 |

shard3   | sizeInBytes | segmentCount |  version |
--------------------------------------------------
replica1 | 72328398189 |           24 | 11978919 |
replica2 | 72329934372 |           20 | 11978971 |

shard4   | sizeInBytes | segmentCount |  version |
--------------------------------------------------
replica1 | 71398290694 |           10 | 11882893 |
replica2 | 71398972036 |           16 | 11883065 |

shard5   | sizeInBytes | segmentCount |  version |
--------------------------------------------------
replica2 | 71635961292 |           16 | 11920521 |
replica1 | 71636668652 |            9 | 11920667 |
```

When i look in the web gui cloud status page everything seems fine. Any idea what happenend / how to fix it?

Comment: I'm curious if this is even a problem - I have the same issue with my SolrCloud running Solr 4.10.3.  I'd really like a solid answer, but I can't find one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done a lot of research on this matter, and the only reference I can find is this email in a Solr mailing list:
[Link](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/lucene-solr-user/201508.mbox/%3CCAE3uTzMGgPRv-P6juwjWM2yYyxfW893xayq7+2haV7MMobmi5g@mail.gmail.com%3E)

> SolrCloud works very differently than the old master-slave replication.
>    The index is NOT copied from the leader to the other replicas, except
>   in extreme recovery circumstances.
>
> Each replica builds its own copy of the index independently from the
>   others.  Due to slight timing differences in the indexing operations,
>   and possible actions related to transaction log replay on node restart,
>   each replica may end up with a different index layout.  There also could
>   be differences in the number of deleted documents.  Unless something
>   goes really wrong, all replicas should contain the same live documents.
>
> Thanks,
>   Shawn

I have seen this same thing in my own experience too.  I just recently created 10 new Solr collections with 2 replicas, loaded several hundred thousand documents into each of the collections, and the versions no longer match.  It seems that the version is a holdover from before the SolrCloud days and it does not need to match.